# Связанные данные в DataGridView на основе DataSet

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset

Программно формирую DataSet на основе загрузки двух DataTable из БД в "ручном" режиме (через некий класс-загрузчик из БД) и также вручную настраиваю связь между ними. Вот так:

```
public void FillDataSet(DataSet ds, string masterName, string detailsName)
{
    if (ds == null) return;

    ds.DataSetName = "Storage";
    using (DataWorker dw = new DataWorker(server, database))
    {
        var masterTable = dw.LoadTable(masterName);
        masterTable.TableName = "Master";
        var detailsTable = dw.LoadTable(detailsName);
        detailsTable.TableName = "Details";
        ds.Tables.Add(masterTable);
        ds.Tables.Add(detailsTable);
        ds.Relations.Add("MasterDetails",
            masterTable.Columns["Id"], detailsTable.Columns["MasterId"]);
    }
}
```

Как я должен привязывать два DataGridView на форме к этому DataSet, чтобы они учитывали связь, и выбор строки в Master в первом DataGridView автоматически показывал только связанные строки во втором?

```
        DataProcessor proc = new DataProcessor(server, database);
        DataSet storage = new DataSet();
        proc.FillDataSet(storage, masterName, detailsName);

        gridMaster.DataSource = storage.Tables[0];
        gridDetails.DataSource = storage.Tables[1];  // ???
```

Answer (score 0):

Так и не разобрался детально в особенностях работы DataAdapter и BuindingSource, с помощью настроек которых можно было бы решить проблему, но кейс, описанный в subj, решил через фильтры.

Важное примечание: я использую GridControl и DataGrid из набора компонент DevExpress (это влияет в примере не способ получения выбранной строки в п.2). В стандартном DataGridView фреймворка WindowsForms получение выбранной строки еще проще.

1. В DataSource обоих Grid-ов подкладываем непосредственно таблицы DataTable:

   ```
        DataProcessor proc = new DataProcessor(server, database);
        storage = new DataSet();
        proc.FillDataSet(storage, masterName, detailsName);

        gridMaster.DataSource = storage.Tables[0];
        gridDetails.DataSource = storage.Tables[1];
   ```
2. По событию SelectionChanged Grid-а Master накладываю фильтр на данные во второй таблице, на основании ключа:

   ```
    private void viewMaster_SelectionChanged(object sender, DevExpress.Data.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int k = viewMaster.GetSelectedRows()[0];
        int id = int.Parse(viewMaster.GetRowCellValue(k, "Id").ToString());

        storage.Tables[1].DefaultView.RowFilter
            = string.Format("MasterId = '{0}'", id);
    }
   ```

Работает довольно быстро, хотя мне и не нравится мой способ получения id мастерской записи. Кто знает, как организовать нужный мне эффект при помощи DataAdapter и/или BuindingSource - напишите, пожалуйста. Напоминаю: исходные вводные заключаются в том, что я добавляю и заполняю две таблицы в DataSet "ручками", а не при помощи мастера подключений и создания встроенной БД приложения!